# Create named Sub-arrays in json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to create named JArrays using JSON.net. I have a list of food, like Milk in the example below.

On initial writing of this data, all food items in the List (say List()) have an array created for each food item, as child arrays in the Items array.

Then later on, when adding a food JObject, I add it to the appropriate sub-array.

The problem is creating the sub-arrays for each item in my list. Maybe it's due to it being 5am, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

PS: I know I could create an example class like the Items class below, however.. I'm trying to do this dynamically. I have a list of data that I can pull the entire food list from (in string format), so it would save hours of tedium if I could do this via the List I have for the food items.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

```cs
class Items{
    public List<string> Milk {get; set;}
    public List<string> Bread {get; set;}
}


    // Example Json
    {
    "Items":[
        "Milk":
        [
            {
                "name": "old milk",
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: how about using JSON.Stringify on a dynamic object that you create

Comment: That worked perfectly. I knew it was the late night programming to blame :( Can you make your comment into an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have the instance of items class here:**

```
Items items = new Items();
```

**Instantiate a new list for milk**:

```
List<string> Milk = new List<string>();
```

**Add items to the list of Milk `string`:**

```
Milk.Add("old milk");
```

**Copy the List to items.Milk :**

```
items.Milk = Milk;
```

**And convert items object into a Json String:**

```
var JsonItems = JSON.Stringify(items);
```

this is just the implementation of the class in your example.

A **better option would be to use the Dictionary object for milk and bread**

ie., it looks something like `milk<"name", "Old milk">`

Hope this helps.